# How to debug why an update won't work with Rails associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to setup a simple rails app with job board functionality. I was able to add jobs to the database, until I added an association between my Job model and devise User model. Now it won't update the database when I fill out the form.

jobs_controller

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def listing
  end

  def listings
  end

  def create

    @job = Job.new(params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :url, :user_id))

    if @job.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @job do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :title, label: "Job title" %>
  <%= form.input :description, label: "Description" %>
  <%= form.input :url, label: "URL" %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <div class="job">
    <h2><%= link_to job.title, job.url %></h2>
    <p><%= job.description %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Add a job", new_job_path %></p>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :jobs
end
```

job.rb

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

end
```

There isn't an error in the console, but the database doesn't seem to be updated or it's not updating the view.

I also ran a migration:

```
class AddUserToJob < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :jobs, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user with `current_user` in Devise.

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  # This restricts the actions to authenticated users and prevents a nil error
  before_action :authenticate_user, except: [:show, :index]

  # ...

  def create
    # this sets the user_id column
    @job = current_user.jobs.new(job_params)
    if @job.save
      # you really should set a flash message or something to notify the user
      # and possibly redirect to the show or index action instead
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private 
  def job_params 
    params.require(:job)
          .permit(:title, :description, :url, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to associate the job immediately to a user, you need to change the association to be optional, like:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

Else you need to supply user_id in your form or set it in the controller action.

---

You should also delegate this part to a separate method

```
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :url, :user_id)
end

Job.new(job_params)
```

Comment: I want it to be required, so every job posting has the user who posted it associated with it. I wouldn't supply user_id in the form because it should be assigned automatically using the credentials of the user who is logged in. How would I set it in the controller action?